# why does this c++ static cast code produce and int not a double

Tags: c++, static-cast

Im new to C++ and i'm not sure why the output for this code is 8 and not 8.25?

can someone explain why this code outputs an int not a double?

Thanks :)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>


int main()
{

double x = 8.25;
    int y;
    y = x;

    double z = static_cast<double>(y);
    std::cout << z << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 8 is a valid value for a double. You rounded 8.25, what did you expect exactly?

Comment: You're doing an implicit cast to an int when you do y = x, so y won't have the decimals. Then when casting it back you're only casting back the 8.

Comment: You guys *do* realise the difference between a comment and an answer, right? :-) Both of those looked like *answers* to me, unlike this (of dubious humour) comment.

Comment: @paxdiablo You are right. I'm not on SO for reputation mining and such kind of questions usually receive answers anyway. That's why I put it in a comment, I didn't have time to turn it in an answer longer than 10 words. My fault.

Comment: @skypjack: It's not just for reputation. Writing answers as answers also increases readability and (supposedly) findability on Google.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yeah. As I said, it was mainly me short in time to formulate properly an answer and I was sure that such a question would have received an answer anyway.

Comment: @Bozemoto -- the code has an **implicit conversion**. There is no such thing as an implicit cast; a cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Comment: @PeteBecker Right you are, english isn't my first language so got the terms mixed up. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 5):

The data is converted to the integer `8` in the statement `y = x`.

A `static_cast` cannot recover the lost ".25" after throwing it away by converting to `int`.

Comment: This is correct. The cast you *should* be using is `temporal_anomoly_cast<>` :-)